# How to dynamically add Docker Container's IP to the Django's ALLOWED_HOST

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-container

I have planned to deploy my Django application in Docker.
For host validation, we need to set the ALLOWED_HOST variable to a domain name or IP address.

How can I add the IP address of the container where my application is being served, to the allowed host?

I don't want to use wildcards or IP range for security reasons. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just include a script as part of the container startup (e.g., your `CMD` or potentially your `ENTRYPOINT`) that grabs the container ip address and places it in a file.  E.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

myaddr=$(ip addr show eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}' | cut -f1 -d/)
sed -i "s/^ALLOWED_HOSTS=.*/ALLOWED_HOSTS=$myaddr/" /path/to/config/file.conf
```

Although honestly, I'm not sure you want to do this...generally, you will access a containerized service via a port that has been published on your host (e.g., via the `-p` option to `docker run`), so rather than the container ip, you would need the host ip (or `localhost`, depending on your use case).

Comment: I suggest `myaddr=$(ip addr sho eth0 |awk -F "[ /]+" '/inet /{print $3}' )` and if ip is registered in DNS `myaddr=$(hostname -i)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a popular python package `netifaces` to dynamically determine the ip address in the settings.py of your djsango application.

you could use the following function to your advantage.

```
import netifaces as ni
ni.ifaddresses('eth0')
ip = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']

allowed_hosts = [ip, '127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better to put in your allowed Host in ur settings.py :

```
allowed_hosts = ['0.0.0.0']
```